# How do you add remote javascript script with custom parameters?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

There are many tutorials on adding js to themes in Drupal 7, but the examples for Omega Sub Themes seem to omit the part about remote scripts, scope and weight:

In the theme `.info` file:

```
scripts[] = js/map.js
```

So how do I specify remote URL, header or footer, and what weight to assign?

```
scripts[] = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&sensor=false
```

results in `<script src="&amp;muqqwd"></script>` and even if it did work, I still need it to be in the header.

Answer (score 2):

External javascript files can't be declared inside the `theme.info` file, unfortunately. Inside your template.php file, you'll have to add something like this:

```
<?php
  drupal_add_js('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&sensor=false', 'external');
```

Comment: The best is to invoke drupal_add_js() from your theme implemtantion of  HOOK_preprocess_page(). See https://drupal.org/node/304255 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
/**
 * Implements template_process_HOOK().
 */
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  $element = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false&libraries=places&key=API_KEY"></script>',
  );

  drupal_add_html_head($element, 'google_maps_js');
}
```

This is based on this [post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1356138#comment-10466789).